# How to compute average but not group them in sql?

Tags: sql, hive

I know that this should be simple, but I can't seem to get it correct.  I want to join tables `A` and `B` and compute an average for unique items in `A`, WITHOUT grouping them.

Table A

```
ID        code
1         10
1         19
2         10
2         11
```

Table B

```
code     value
10       0.3
11       0.5
19       0.1
```

I want to join on the `code`, but then compute the average of the corresponding values for each `ID`:
The resulting table should be

```
ID     codes   average
1      10      0.2
1      19      0.2
2      10      0.4
2      10      0.4
```

Does this make sense?

I know that one can use a `group by` and then an `avg(` to aggregate them, but I'm not looking to aggregate, I want to keep the duplicate average values in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `over(partition by...)` along with your `Avg`.

```
SELECT A.ID
    , A.CODE
    , AVG(B.VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID)
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
on a.code = b.code
```

Comment: Good. This does not seem to work in HIVE though because I think the language features are not supported.

Answer (score -2):

The straightforward solution is subqueries:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.code, 
  (SELECT AVG(B.value) 
   FROM B INNER JOIN A A2 ON B.code = A2.code
   WHERE A.id = B.id) AVERAGE
FROM A
```

Comment: It does not do the average per ID.

Comment: Yeah I do not think this will get the averages for each ID, it will just get the averages across all.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the requirement, fixed now.

Comment: There's no ID in table `B`, and you ask for rows `WHERE A.id = B.id`

Comment: Would you like your money back? Hopefully you can figure out the details from here.